# PostgreSQL Transaction fails: "there is no transaction in progress"

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, transactions

I've got a pretty long transaction I'm trying to execute using JDBC for PostgreSQL. In JDBC I can't use `COMMIT` and `ROLLBACK`, so I'm trying to implement my desired behaviour in Java code...

```
try {
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

    con.setAutoCommit(false);
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    st.execute(myHugeTransaction);

    con.commit();
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    try {
        con.rollback();
    } catch (SQLException ex1) {
        // log...
    }
    // log...
}
```

For small statements, this works pretty well, but for the large ones with about 10K statements in a single transaction, this fails in the `con.commit` line with

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: kind mismatch among backends. Possible last query was: "COMMIT" kind details are: 0[C] 1[N: there is no transaction in progress]
```

The funny thing is, if I catch SQL Warnings with `st.getWarnings();` I can see that the database is actually processing the whole script I've sent, just when it comes to the commit, it all fails.

btw, the transaction is totally fine. I write an exact copy of it into a file and I can run it without errors by copying it into pgAdmin. Hope you can help me on that one, I've been searching and testing stuff for hours now...

**edit**

Maybe I didn't get this right, so two questions:

1. Can I execute multiple statements in one call to `Statement.execute()`?
2. If not, what is the right way to run a Script with multiple statements using JDBC (without the need to parse and split it into single statements)?

Comment: You aren't doing anything that does a commit in your script (either directly or indirectly)?

Comment: This error comes from pgpool. You're probably throwing a multi-statement query that is not supported by your pgpool configuration.

Comment: If you are executing multiple statements in one call to 'Statement.execute()`, then you're not using the JDBC API as intended.

Comment: There's no BEGIN, COMMIT or ROLLBACK in my script. Yes, I'm using a multi-statement, but no query (just DROP, ALTER, CREATE). And multiple statements in one call are working for smaller scripts, but if it's not intended - how do I execute such a script? I'd need to write a full SQL parser to split my script into single statements...

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, if this is a SQL script you are better off doing a shell escape to psql.  That is the best way to handle this.  In general I have had way too many unpleasant surprises from people trying to parse out SQL code and run it against the db.  This way madness lies.

you say "smaller scripts" which leads me to conclude you are doing something like setting up a database (or upgrading one, but that's less likely since there are no queries).  Use psql through a shell escape and don't look back.  That really is the best way.

I suppose if you have to you could try adding explicit BEGIN and COMMIT to your script.

I am not sure why it seems to be committing the transaction implicitly.  you have set autocommit off properly.  There are no obvious problems in your code.  Is  it possible you have an old or buggy JDBC driver?  If not, I would recommend filing a bug report with the PostgreSQL JDBC driver project.